# Dagger 2: Make a class injectable in other classes Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am developing an Android project with Kotlin and Dagger 2. I have a `MyModule` in which I defined some provider functions.

```
@Module
object MyModule {
   @Provides
   @JvmStatic 
   internal fun provideSomething(): Something {
      ...
   }
}
```

In my `Foo` class, I inject `Something` as a member variable:

```
class Foo(@Inject val something: Something) {
}
```

But now I want to have this `Foo` class also be injectable to another class, e.g. in a class called `Bar`:

```
class Bar(@Inject val foo: Foo)
```

How to make that happen? If in Java I could do:

```
class Foo {
  // I inject something
  @Inject
  private Something something;

  // I also make Foo to be injectable to other class
  @Inject
  public Foo()
}
```

But how to achieve the same in my Kotlin `Foo` class?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Something` is a class created by you. You don't even need a `@Module` to provide it.

You can do this,

```
class Something @Inject constructor() {

}
```

You just add @Inject to `Something` constructor and that's it, **Dagger** knows how to provide it. And then in your `Foo` class

```
class Foo @Inject constructor() {

  @Inject
  lateinit var something: Something

}
```

Done, no need to have @Module and @Component if you own `Something` class.

**But**

If the class `Something` is not under your control then we need to take the long route such as,

**Step 1:  Create Module**

```
@Module
object MyModule {
   @Provides
   @JvmStatic 
   internal fun provideSomething(): Something {
      ...
   }
}
```

**Step 2: Define Component**

```
@Component(modules = [MyModule::class])
interface MyComponent {
    fun inject(foo: Foo) //mention the place where you need to inject variables
}
```

**Step 3: Start Component**

```
    class Foo @Inject constructor(){

          @Inject
          lateinit var something:Something

            init{
               DaggerMyComponent().create().inject(this) //do this before using `something` or else face `UninitializedPropertyException`

             //You can now freely use `something`, **Dagger** has already performed his magic
            }


        }
```

**Update:**

Let's say `Something` has a parameterized constructor and looks like this,
`class Something @Inject constructor(mRandom : RandomClass)`, again two possibilities arise

If `RandomClass` is owned by you, you can just add @Inject to this `RandomClass` constructor like this,

```
class RandomClass @Inject constructor(){
}
```

that's it, **Dagger** will provide `RandomClass` wherever needed.

And If `RandomClass` is not under your control you need to provide it using a `@Module` like this,

```
@Module
object RandomModule {
    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    fun providesRandomClass(): RandomClass {
         ...
     }
}
```

Add this `@Module` to your `@Component` and start the `@Component` wherever dependencies are needed(*Example is already provided above in steps*).

Moral of the story is, **One way or another Dagger should know how to provide** `RandomClass`

For your specific example, let's say we have

```
class Something @Inject constructor(mString:String,customType:CustomType){
}
```

Just tell **Dagger**  how to provide that `String` and `CustomType`

```
@Module
    object CustomModule {

        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        @Named("AnyName") //Just to differentiate which string we need
        fun providesString() = "AnyName"

        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        fun providesCustomType(): CustomType {
             ...
         }
    }
```

and then this last little modification over `Something` constructor,

```
class Something @Inject constructor( @Named("AnyName") mString:String, customType:CustomType ){

}
```

Comment: Thanks, is your answer assumed that the constructor of `Something` has no arguments ? what if `Something`'s constructor also have argments, would adding @Inject to `Something` constructor be fine? I know it depends on how the arguments in constructor is provided, but let's assume the arguments are String and a custom type let's say a class called "Anotherthing", how to handle in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin you have to do it like this:

```
class Foo @Inject constructor(val something: Something) {
}
```

I'm not so sure if you can name them the same either.

Comment: Do you miss a `@Inject` before `val something: Something` in constructor? Because `something` is injected there if you see the Java code. or am I wrong?

Comment: you have to determin whether you are doing constructor injection or field injection and field injection is not done like that in Java/Kotlin

Comment: also, if Dagger knows how to create a `Foo` , `Foo` is already injectable

Comment: but my Java code shows what I need. It is a field injection in `Foo` for `something`, in this answer, I feel it is missing that. If just take my Java code as a reference.

Comment: For example, with this answer, when I create an instance of `Foo` I still need to specify an instance of `Something` like `val foo = Foo(something)`, but I hope dagger could inject `something` for me inside `Foo` so that I only need to do `val foo = Foo()`. How to achieve it?

Comment: I am reading , in the meantime, do you see the problem I explained with current answer? I can't do `val foo = Foo()` but have to specify a instance of `something` to feed to the constructor which I hoped dagger could do for me. But with the Java code I showed, I can `Foo foo = new Foo()`, dagger injects the `something` for me. Overall, I just want to know a kotlin version for that Java code I showed.

Comment: you either inject by field injection or constructor injection